# Matplotlib. Как реализовать скроллбар?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Всем привет.
Пытаюсь изучать язык Python + библиотеку Matplotlib и на данный момент я застрял с некоторыми моментами:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFz7e.png

Первый:

Я не знаю, как я могу удалить (в окне), нотации (axex: х,Y и их координаты) которые видно на скрине?

Второй:

Я хотел бы знать - могу ли я установить полосу прокрутки на любом графике? Я имею в виду, мне нужна фиксированная Ширина на графике и если содержание (какое-то количество точек или японские свечи) внутри него будут расти(по ширине) - мне нужно появление полосы прокрутки с низу чарта.

Это можно реализовать на нейтивном Python + matplotlib? (без wx Python, tkinter и т.д. и т.п.)

P. S. Буду признателен за любые конструктивные советы.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что касается полосы прокрутки, то ее можно сделать при помощи виджета "Slider", но это будет не совсем просто.

Попробуйте вот такой пример:

```
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import math

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

t = [i / 100. for i in range(0, int(math.pi) * 100, 1)]

s = [math.sin(i * 20) for i in t]
l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2, color='red')
plt.axis([0, 1, -10, 10])

axcolor = 'gray'
ax_x_pos = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)

wsize = 10

x_pos = Slider(ax_x_pos, 'Position', 0, len(t) - wsize - 1, valfmt='%d', valinit=0)

ax.set_xlim(t[0], t[wsize])
ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1)


def update(val):
    print(x_pos.val)
    pos = int(x_pos.val)
    ax.set_xlim(t[pos], t[pos + wsize])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

x_pos.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Чтобы убрать отображение координат, необходимо заменить функцию вывода на "пустышку":

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.figure(1)
plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
plt.gca().format_coord = lambda x, y: ''
plt.show()
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример.
Это то что надо.

А на счет белого поля с низу(с нотациями) - вы случайно не в курсе как это дело можно привалить?

Comment: Добавил в ответ пример удаления вывода координат.

Comment: Такой момент еще хотел для себя выяснить на будущее:
Вертикальный скролл уже невозможно будет реализовать подобным образом?
(пока из того что нагуглил - говорилось, что невозможно.)
+ момент по отключению слайдера хотел прояснить - в доке говорится(если я ничего не напутал) что за это отвечает следующая функция: disconnect(cid)
Вопрос:
Каким образом ее можно применить не могу понять
(куда подключать этот код + с каким параметром вместо "cid") ?
(что бы например если у меня элементов мало было в чарте - слайдер исчезал + мог появится снова, если кол-во элементов увеличится.. )

Comment: Вертикальный скролл можно сделать таким же способом. Только вместо установки диапазона по x `set_xlim` будет вызов по y `set_ylim`.

cid это идентификатор подключения. В приведенном мной примере, cid можно получить вот так: `cid = x_pos.on_changed(update)`, а затем отключить слайдер: `x_pos.disconnect(cid)`.

Comment: Но лучше не отключать, а просто не подключать сигнал.

Comment: Cмотрите:
Я имел ввиду на счет вертикального скролл бара следующий вариант:
[ссылка](https://yadi.sk/i/FyhMLbuyxp4no)
То есть что бы он располагался перпендикулярно оси X.
И при этом что бы можно было переключать масштабирование по оси Y скроля это полоску именно вверх-вниз(а не в право - в лево.)
Это реально?(такое реализовать.)
+ еще мне интересно можно ли как то курсор менять(например что бы рука отображалась как в браузерах при наведении.) в матплотлибе - при наведении(в данном случае на скроллбар)?
У же гуглил перегуглил + че только не пробовал - ниче не выходит пока что..

Comment: В библиотеке нет возможности сделать вертикальный слайдер, поэтому чтобы сделать его вертикальным, необходимо будет использовать наследование, и там переопределять методы отрисовки. Проще всего реализовать такие задачи непосредственно средствами бэкенда, который используется для GUI. Например на PyQt.